# ActionBarSherlock with google mapview tab

Tags: java, android, mapactivity, actionbarsherlock-map

I have been trying to get actionbarsherlock tab work with google mapview, but couldn't figured out how, I have implemented google map (MapActivity) with custom overlay working but don't want to modified too much to get the sherlock tap working. Could someone please show me how to do it? I have followed this link and use google instead of esri map library, but never success. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/59190-Map-View-in-Fragment-with-Tab-Action-Bar
 Thank you